# PHP preg_plit() with line breaks but prevent multi line jumps

Tags: php, arrays, string, line-breaks, preg-split

I would like to preg_split() a string every new line, only line with content (no multi line jumps)

I tried this `(\S*)\n|$`

For example:

```
last_name, first_name

bjorge, philip
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
```

my preg_split

```
(\S*)\n|$
```

```
array(2
0   =>  last_name, first_name
1   =>  
)
array(2
0   =>  
1   =>  
)
array(2
0   =>  bjorge, philip
1   =>  
)
array(2
0   =>  kardashian, kim
1   =>  
)
array(2
0   =>  mercury, freddie
1   =>  
)
```

What I would like as an array:

```
array(2
0   =>  last_name, first_name
)
array(2
0   =>  bjorge, philip
)
array(2
0   =>  kardashian, kim 
)
array(2
0   =>  mercury, freddie    
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split on `\R+` that means 1 or more any kind of linebreak.

**Edit according to comment:**

In order to not capture lines that contain only spaces, add `\h+` (i.e. 1 or more horizontal spaces):

```
$string = "last_name, first_name

bjorge, philip
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
";
$res = preg_split('/\h*\R+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => last_name, first_name
    [1] => bjorge, philip
    [2] => kardashian, kim
    [3] => mercury, freddie
)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I have the problem with a line like one space and \n.
How would I use \S* ? (to avoid the case of one line with a space)

Comment: Watch out because you answer make me ```Array
(
    [0] => last_name, first_name

    [1] => bjorge, philip
kardashian, kim
mercury, freddie
)``` (one line with a space separate in two row)

Comment: @SourouCerulean: Sorry, I would say `\h*\R+` with a star after the h, not a plus.